# How to count total items on the ground

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Items on the ground clump together in stacks, so getting the number of entities doesn't give me the number of items there are. Is there a way to count the number of items instead of the number of item entities?

Comment: So you mean if there was one stack of 64 items on the ground, it would only see it as 1 item?

Comment: I rewrote the question to make it clearer what you wanted, I hope that's ok with you. Context for everyone else. This question started from [this comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/348388/minecraft-executing-if-more-than-500-entities/348392?noredirect=1#comment492968_348392).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't really sure how to word it xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a scoreboard to store the amount of items per entity into:

```
/scoreboard objectives add count dummy
```

Then you can easily transfer the stack size of every item entity into their "count" scoreboard like this:

```
/execute as @e[type=item] store result score @s count run data get entity @s Item.Count
```

If you want to do this only for a certain type of item, you can filter that as well:

```
/execute as @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:stone"}}] store result score @s count run data get entity @s Item.Count
```

Then you just need to add all those scores up to a shared score, for example yours:

```
/scoreboard players operation @s count += @e[type=item] count
```

Of course if you want to do this multiple times, you have to reset your score before the next repetition:

```
/scoreboard players reset @s count
```